# How to run Applet with dependencies jar file in HTML

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I have a jar file containing applet files which are dependent of below additional jar file.
Its running fine as standalone jar file.  The applet uses:

1. `xmlrpc-2.0.jar`
2. `commons-codec-1.3.jar`

But when I tried to run in HTML as below, it's running, but attached additional jar files are not binding with it. How can I fix the problem?

```
<html>
<body>
<APPLET 
  CODE="MAIN.class"
  WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%"
  ARCHIVE = "MAIN.jar,xmlrpc-2.0.jar,commons-codec-1.3.jar"
  >
This example uses an applet.
</APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MAIN
Created-By: 1.3.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: xmlrpc-2.0.jar commons-codec-1.3.jar
Name: MAIN.class
```

Comment: There's no `APPLET` tag in any recent version of HTML, only `applet`, same for the attributes `code`, `width`, `height`, `archive`.

Comment: what error do you get? classNotFound? for classes located in other jars?
One more silly question, is your main class at default package? because there should be full package name at the code="" attribute

Comment: Hope you know that code signing required for applet since `1st January, 2014`

Answer (score 0):

It should work as long as the jar files are in the same folder than your MAIN.jar.  Can you see any classpath-related error in the Java console?

You can also try to use a manifest file as described [here](http://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/specifying-jar-file-dependencies-at-applet-tags-archive-parameter-or-at-jars-manifest-file/).

Comment: I used the same already in MAIN.jar file Its work fine without html. :Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MAIN
Created-By: 1.3.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: xmlrpc-2.0.jar commons-codec-1.3.jar
Name: MAIN.class

Answer (score 0):

[FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse worked for me.  Just be careful when you have multiple projects open, since it has a tendency to grab other stuff from non-related projects and roll that into your fatjar too.